# Gnuplot says file is unreadable

Tags: file-io, gnuplot

I have a file called "data_prova.dat" in my folder, as you can see:

> gnuplot> !ls
>
> data_prova.dat

But when I ask gnuplot to plot it, it says:

> warning: Skipping unreadable file "./data_prova.dat"
>
> No data in plot

which is just false, because:

> wc -c data_prova.dat
>
> 2640413132 data_prova.dat

Can this be because the file is too large?

Comment: It says `unreadable` Could be premissions or invalid data or simply to big.

Comment: It is telling you the file is ***unreadable***, not that it is ***not present***.  Big difference.

Comment: got any reference on the maximum readable size?

Comment: Please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493703/how-to-create-a-data-file-for-gnuplot), it may just be a data format problem and not a size problem.  There is no hardcoded size limit

Comment: Thanks, the format is not the problem, because everything has worked other times and this is the output of a .c file. In any case, I shortened it and now it gets plotted, so it must be an issue with the size.

Comment: Are you sure you need 2 billion characters? You only have order of millions of pixels to fill...

Answer (score -1):

I changed my file name and it's now working.